# How do we use tf.image.encode_jpeg to write out an image in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Given a Tensor, I would like to use this function to get a 0D string and then write this out as "sample.jpg".

This can be easily achieved by OpenCV or Python PIL, but I would like to keep everything within TF if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In tensorflow the function would look like:

```
 import tensorflow as tf


def write_jpeg(data, filepath):
    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
        data_t = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8)
        op = tf.image.encode_jpeg(data_t, format='rgb', quality=100)
        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        data_np = sess.run(op, feed_dict={ data_t: data })

    with open(filepath, 'w') as fd:
        fd.write(data_np)


import numpy as np

R = np.zeros([128 * 128])
G = np.ones([128 * 128]) * 100
B = np.ones([128 * 128]) * 200

data = np.array(list(zip(R, G, B)), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(128, 128, 3)

assert data.shape == (128, 128, 3)

write_jpeg(data, "./test.jpeg")
```

the numpy part can be improved but it was for demonstration purposes only

Comment: It looks like the final data format is byte not string. I had to change "with open(filepath, 'w') as fd:
        fd.write(data_np)" to 

"with open(filepath, 'wb') as fd:
        fd.write(data_np)" in Python 3.5 and Tensorflow 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can evaulate the image and use opencv or PIL to save it.

```
import cv2 # opencv
from scipy.misc import imsave

... network generates an image ...
out = network(input)
img = tf.image.encode_jpeg(out)

img_to_save = img.eval(feed_dict)
# cv2.imwrite("myimage", img_to_save)
imsave("myimage.jpeg", img_to_save)
```

your image may or may not need a feed_dict to be evaluated.

Comment: What is data type of img?

Comment: img is a tensorflow variable (or a tensor).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the img variable is a tensor, it could be like <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>, right?

Comment: Yes, however as that's dictated by the backend and not part of the standard the type itself might change over time.  So today (May 30, 2017) that type is correct, tomorrow it could be something else.